# When is mariadb creating tmp tables?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, temporary-tables, optimization, query-performance

I have found, that `copying to tmp table` is taking most of the time of a slow query, that I wanted to optimize. I watched the output of 'profiling' in a terminal. This happens on a pics table with 6000 rows and a user table with 30 rows.

```
...
| Copying to tmp table | 0.000263 |
| Copying to tmp table | 0.052237 |
| Sorting result | 0.000035 |
...
```

Why (or when) is mariadb using tmp tables? Can I change the query to avoid using tmp tables?

```
SELECT `pics`.*, `users`.`username`, `users`.`displayname` 
FROM `pics` 
LEFT JOIN `users` 
    ON `users`.`id` = `pics`.`user_id` 
ORDER BY RAND() asc 
LIMIT 4;
```

I have these indexes:

pics:

```
PRIMARY id
UNIQUE  created_at
INDEX   user_id
INDEX   location
```

users:

```
PRIMARY id
UNIQUE  username
```

## edit:

i have another one, also slow, and also because of `copying to tmp table`:

```
SELECT t.tag, count(pt.tag_id) as anzahl 
FROM tags t
JOIN pic_tag pt 
    ON t.id = pt.tag_id
GROUP BY t.tag COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 12;
```

## show profile for query 1;

```
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000149 |
| checking permissions | 0.000009 |
| checking permissions | 0.000008 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000031 |
| After opening tables | 0.000010 |
| System lock          | 0.000010 |
| Table lock           | 0.000008 |
| After table lock     | 0.000012 |
| init                 | 0.000058 |
| optimizing           | 0.000028 |
| statistics           | 0.000061 |
| preparing            | 0.000045 |
| executing            | 0.000007 |
| Copying to tmp table | 0.000101 |
| Copying to tmp table | 0.034019 |
| Sorting result       | 0.000426 |
| Sending data         | 0.000023 |
| end                  | 0.000006 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000129 |
| end                  | 0.000004 |
| query end            | 0.000003 |
| closing tables       | 0.000011 |
| freeing items        | 0.000006 |
| updating status      | 0.000012 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000003 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

## SHOW STATUS like 'Hand%';

```
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 0     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 0     |
| Handler_icp_attempts       | 0     |
| Handler_icp_match          | 0     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_mrr_key_refills    | 0     |
| Handler_mrr_rowid_refills  | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 0     |
| Handler_read_key           | 13759 |
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 11501 |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 12    |
| Handler_read_rnd_deleted   | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 4292  |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_tmp_update         | 9495  |
| Handler_tmp_write          | 2031  |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 0     |
+----------------------------+-------+
```

## explain

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+--------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref          | rows | Extra                           |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+--------------+------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL   | NULL    | NULL         | 2258 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | pt    | ref  | tag_id        | tag_id | 4       | website.t.id |    5 | Using index                     |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+--------+---------+--------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

it takes about 23ms. the tags table has about 2000 rows and the pic_tag is a pivot(?) table where the relation of pics and tags is saved. (pic_id - tag_id) it has about 11000 rows.

I think UNION would almost be too much code, for 12 or 15 or something tags that i want to show. Is there no way to somehow deal with the tmp table? Or is the tmp table itself not the problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with MySQL, but I'd try the random limited select on pics in an inner query, and join on users outside - looks like it is materializing that "where-less" join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the famous article "[fixing `ORDER BY rand()`](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/)", and in particular the [multiple-selection via union](http://jan.kneschke.de/2007/2/22/analyzing-complex-queries/), we can write this:

```
(
 SELECT   `p1`.*,
          `users`.`username`,
          `users`.`displayname`
 FROM     pics p1
 JOIN
          (SELECT ceil(rand() *
                  (SELECT max(id)
                   FROM   pics)) AS id
          ) AS p2
 JOIN     users
 ON       users.id = p1.user_id
 WHERE    p1.id >= p2.id
 ORDER BY p1.id ASC limit 1
)
UNION ALL
(
 SELECT   `p1`.*,
          `users`.`username`,
          `users`.`displayname`
 FROM     pics p1
 JOIN
          (SELECT ceil(rand() *
                  (SELECT max(id)
                   FROM   pics)) AS id
          ) AS p2
 JOIN     users
 ON       users.id = p1.user_id
 WHERE    p1.id >= p2.id
 ORDER BY p1.id ASC limit 1
)
UNION ALL
(
 SELECT   `p1`.*,
          `users`.`username`,
          `users`.`displayname`
 FROM     pics p1
 JOIN
          (SELECT ceil(rand() *
                  (SELECT max(id)
                   FROM   pics)) AS id
          ) AS p2
 JOIN     users
 ON       users.id = p1.user_id
 WHERE    p1.id >= p2.id
 ORDER BY p1.id ASC limit 1
)
UNION ALL
(
 SELECT   `p1`.*,
          `users`.`username`,
          `users`.`displayname`
 FROM     pics p1
 JOIN
          (SELECT ceil(rand() *
                  (SELECT max(id)
                   FROM   pics)) AS id
          ) AS p2
 JOIN     users
 ON       users.id = p1.user_id
 WHERE    p1.id >= p2.id
 ORDER BY p1.id ASC limit 1
)
```

This method does not create perfect random numbers because it assumes that the distribution of ids is regular. Also, the union all may select a row twice. It is not the exact same query, either, I used an `INNER JOIN` in order not to select users without pictures, but that is easily fixable.

Your method (`ORDER BY rand()`) in 5.6 (which may have been optimized already in respect to 5.5):

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS like 'Hand%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 4     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 1     |
| Handler_read_key           | 6041  |
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 0     |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 4     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 12122 |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 6060  |
+----------------------------+-------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My method (article's one):

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS like 'Hand%';
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 24    |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 4     |
| Handler_read_key           | 12    |
| Handler_read_last          | 4     |
| Handler_read_next          | 0     |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 9     |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 8     |
+----------------------------+-------+
18 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

As you can see, reads and writes have been changed from thousands to 12 reads and 8 writes.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: it is indeed decreasing query time from about 40ms to about 2-5ms